# Creating a JWT through Powershell with a private key

Tags: powershell, jwt

I am trying to create a JWT through Powershell, but I don't know what to do. I have created the header and the payload and now I think I need to sign it with a private key.

The private key is in a file and looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
LoremipsumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelitNullanonex
seddolorportafaucibusPellentesquehabitantmorbitristiquese
nectusetnetusetmalesuadafamesacturpisegestasVestibulumpos
uerelobortismalesuadaNamatmetusidodioconsectetursagittise
tnonlacusMorbifringillasempertempusDonecsitametfelisnecma
ssapulvinarpretiuminutnislPellentesquejustopuruslobortist
ristiquesuscipitidmattisnonturpisVestibulumsuscipitidveli
tsitametporttitorPraesenttemporcursuspretiumNullavelarcus
itametexaliquamtinciduntNamsagittisfelissedorcimattislobo
rtisMaecenasvariusnonpurusetaccumsanDuisinantesitametnibh
rhoncusauctorPellentesquehabitantmorbitristiquesenectuset
netusetmalesuadafamesacturpisegestas
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have to use RS256 as the algorithm, but I can't figure it out..

Comment: There are a lot of example https://gist.github.com/cvzi/d547ac611a09666b9a150106d20bdd77

Comment: You didn't specify the language.

Comment: It says Powershell in the header and in the body..